# Find a date in the header with Range.Find

Tags: excel, vba

I updated a task/stat tracker workbook to adjust the start date for the range of days across the top. This broke my "range.find" Sub on the back end. Now it can't find the current date.

Finding the date in the header informs the "Post" function to place the values in the correct column via a `sheet.cells(myDate.Row, myDate.Column)` type line of code.

I created a sample worksheet (in same workbook) with a button and a simple macro that replicates the backend sub for this question.

The button/worksheet-level Sub found the value as expected.
The simple button and the main project sub are identical.

Code I wrote to post my problem.

```vb
Public dateOne As Range
Public testDate As Variant
Public wb As Workbook
Public testSht As Worksheet

Public Sub loadRange()
    Set wb = Workbooks("Tracker 2.1 - CAOC Edition DEV")
    Set testSht = wb.Sheets("TEST")
    
    Set dateOne = testSht.Range("E2:M2")
End Sub

Sub findDateOne()
    'this one uses a Range.Find
    loadRange
    
    Set testDate = dateOne.Find(What:=DateValue(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    testSht.Cells(15, 2).Value = testDate
    testSht.Cells(17, 2).Value = testDate.row
    testSht.Cells(18, 2).Value = testDate.Column
    
End Sub
```

My current back end code:

```vb
Public Sub currentDate()
'sub to assign current date to global values
    MsgBox("WTF")
    'This can no longer find the correct date since I converted to a 
    'formula system to allow for re-use
    
    Set myDate = taskRange.Find(What:=DateValue(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If myDate Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Date not found")
    Else
        MsgBox(myDate.Address)
    End If  
End Sub
```

`myDate` is a Variant, `taskRange` is set via a separate loadData() sub.

The range that it's searching is a row of dates, based off of a start date. EG: cell A1 is 6/24/2023, subsequent cells are A1+1, B1+1, etc. On the worksheet, the values are formatted as Date.

1. Why is it not working?
2. Why is it working on my example sheet?

Comment: What is `DateValue(Date)` supposed to do?

Comment: Date is VBA's version of Excel's NOW function. It returns today's date. DateValue is a built-in function that converts it to Excel's number system for dates. Example, today is 45101 in "Excel-speak"

Comment: *"Date is VBA's version of Excel's NOW function"* - it isn't. Excel's `NOW` function returns the current date with time. `Date` returns the current date without time. The VBA's version of Excel's `NOW` function is [`Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function). *"DateValue is a built-in function that converts it to Excel's number system for dates"* - it doesn't. `DateValue` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function) `Variant/Date` just like `Date` and `Now`.

Comment: So `DateValue(Date)` should be replaced with [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function).

Comment: Debug.Print DateValue(Date) = Date   ... print out TRUE, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @GSerg     My bad. Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ   I figured as much.. my guess is there's a disconnect between the cell's value and what the Find function is looking for. But as I stated in my post, the exact same code works on a different sheet, which would seemingly indicate that there *isn't* a type mismatch going on.

Comment: What does "not in my main code" mean? Does it return "Date not found" message? Anyhow, `testDate` is good to be declared as `Range`. This is what `Find` function returns. Excel is able to guess in most of the cases, but no sense to not declare it as the object you know it must be. Then, are you sure that the searched range is formatted as `Date`? Did you use `Find`, in the meantime, even manually and changed some search parameters? It uses the last used ones and you maybe need to add more parameters. Can you share a dummy such file with only one sheet to be tested?

Comment: @FaneDuru "not in my main code" means not in the module that holds all of my other code for my userforms and functions. The currentDate() sub does return the "Date not found" when run. I've created a completely new Workbook and Worksheet with the code and example data, and it works. That's my issue. It will work on the test sheet, but won't work when essentially the same code is run via my userform call. I'm not sure how to share a dummy file... I'm not sure how that will help though, unless there's a way I can share the whole original .xlsm file.

Comment: No need to share the .xml file. Only a sheet you consider eloquent (maybe the one where the code does not work) in a xlsx workbook. Just for us to make tests and find a solution (probably, using more `Find` parameters. You can use a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/), for instance, is free and easy to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find Today's Date in a Row

[image]

**Find**

- The `Find` method has many arguments so make use of them.
- I got it to work with the `LookAt` argument set to `xlPart` but that may be a locale issue (mine isn't US). Anyone's feedback is welcome since IMO it should have been `xlWhole`.

```vb
Sub Testfind()
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = Sheet1.Rows(1)
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    Set dcell = rrg.Find(Date, rrg.Cells(rrg.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
    ' '.Cells(.Cells.Count)' to ensure the left-most occurrence
    ' since the 6th argument, 'SearchDirection', is by default 'xlNext'.
    
    If dcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Today's date not found.", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "Today's date found in cell """ _
            & dcell.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
    End If
           
End Sub
```

**Application.Match**

- I prefer the following alternative.

```vb
Sub TestMatch()

    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = Sheet1.Rows(1)
    
    Dim cIndex: cIndex = Application.Match(CLng(Date), rrg, 0)
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then Set dcell = rrg.Cells(cIndex)
    
    If dcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Today's date not found.", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "Today's date found in cell """ _
            & dcell.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
    End If
           
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your preferred solution works to find the date now, but I'm running into an issue later when I try to use the .Row and .Column of the dcell Range variable.

This is the line to be exact:
`With wsTasks.Cells(myDate.row + (tskLoc(i) - 2), myDate.Column)`

and it doesn't crash per se.. just exits out of the sub immediately.. any ideas? or would that be a new question?

Comment: I guess that's a new question but you can simplify it with `With myDate.Offset(tskLoc(i) - 2)` if the cell is on `wsTasks`. I hope you have explicitly declared `Dim myDate As Range`. Also, note that in your expression, the parentheses around `tskLoc(i) - 2` are redundant; maybe you meant to use `tskLoc(i - 2)` (a wild guess).

Comment: So the .Offset didn't work for me, but all your other suggestions got me up and running! The next hiccup I know how to solve, so thank you so much for your help!!